# Прокрутка Слайдера ползунком

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slick.js

Здравствуйте какая задача)))
Нужно подвязать ползунок к slick слайдеру чтобы при перетягивании ползунка слайдер вращался))
Если нужно будет предоставить еще что-то пишите)))
Заранее Очень сильно Благодарю!!!

Использую jquery-3.2.1.min.js, jquery-ui.min.js, slick.js.

[image: **Фото**]

Comment: Не помешало бы исходник, который не работает. Вопрос выглядит как ТЗ.

Comment: а можна ссылку на исходный файл скинуть?

Comment: Сделайте у rage шаг 1 и при увеличение или уменьшении значения присваивайте соответствующему index-у слайда класс active.  То есть "value = 1" ->   "slide1 == active"

Answer (score 3):

```js
$('.slider-nav').slick({ 
  infinite: true,
  speed: 500,
  fade: true,
  cssEase: 'linear'
});   
      
 $('input[type="range"]').on("input change", function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
   var slideno = $(this).val(); 
   $('.slider-nav').slick('slickGoTo', slideno-1 );
 });
```

```css
body{
  background:#ccc;
}
.main {
  font-family:Arial;
  width:500px;
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
}
h3 {
    background: #fff;
    color: #3498db;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 2%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.action{
  display:block; 
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
.action a {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px 10px; 
  background:#f30;
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.action a:hover{
  background:#000;
}

a.active {
    background: #00ff45 !important;
}
.slider.slider-nav.slick-initialized.slick-slider {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.css">
 


<div class="main"> 
  <div class="slider slider-nav">
    <div><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div><h3>2</h3></div>
    <div><h3>3</h3></div>
    <div><h3>4</h3></div>
    <div><h3>5</h3></div>
  </div>
  <div class="action">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="5"  value="0" step="1">
  </div>
</div>
```